# How to solve a simple differential equations?

Tags: differential

I have a problem about differential equations.

$\dot{x}(t) = - \lambda x(t)+b$

How to solve this equations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{fry}}$ try?

Comment: $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = - \lambda x(t)+b$ 


`$\frac{dx(t)}{ x(t) } = - \lambda dt +\frac{b dt}{x(t)}$'

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The easiest way could be to define $$x(t)=y(t)+\frac b\lambda \implies x'(t)=y't)\implies y'(t)=-\lambda y(t)$$ which looks very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Separate variables:

$\frac{dx}{-\lambda x + b} = dt$

And integrate both sides.